# TObjectList<T>.IndexOf giving incorrect result

Tags: delphi, generics

I am trying to understand why the way I use `TObjectList<T>.IndexOf` is not working for me.

The following is a small example

```
program Project3;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  madExcept,
  madLinkDisAsm,
  madListHardware,
  madListProcesses,
  madListModules,
  System.Generics.Defaults,
  System.Generics.Collections,
  System.Contnrs,
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TRecordObject = class(TObject)
    ID: Integer;
    Price: Currency;
    Matched: Boolean;
  public
    constructor Create(aSort: Integer; aPrice, aSize: Currency; aID: string; aNewParam: Integer;
      aSecondPrice, aSecondSize: Currency; aMatched: boolean); reintroduce;
  end;

  TSortCriterion<T> = class(TObject)
    Ascending: Boolean;
    Comparer: IComparer<T>;
  end;

  TSortCriteriaComparer<T> = class(TComparer<T>)
  private
    SortCriteria: TObjectList<TSortCriterion<T>>;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function Compare(const Right, Left: T): Integer; override;
    procedure ClearCriteria; virtual;
    procedure AddCriterion(NewCriterion: TSortCriterion<T>); virtual;
  end;

  TIDComparer = class(TComparer<TRecordObject>)
  public
    function Compare(const Left, Right: TRecordObject): Integer; override;
  end;

  TMatchedComparer = class(TComparer<TRecordObject>)
  public
    function Compare(const Left, Right: TRecordObject): Integer; override;
  end;

procedure TSortCriteriaComparer<T>.AddCriterion(NewCriterion: TSortCriterion<T>);
begin
  SortCriteria.Add(NewCriterion);
end;

procedure TSortCriteriaComparer<T>.ClearCriteria;
begin
  SortCriteria.Clear;
end;

function TSortCriteriaComparer<T>.Compare(const Right, Left: T): Integer;
var
  Criterion: TSortCriterion<T>;
begin
  for Criterion in SortCriteria do
  begin
    Result := Criterion.Comparer.Compare(Right, Left);
    if not Criterion.Ascending then
      Result := -Result;
    if Result <> 0 then
      Exit;
  end;
end;

constructor TSortCriteriaComparer<T>.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  SortCriteria := TObjectList<TSortCriterion<T>>.Create(True);
end;

destructor TSortCriteriaComparer<T>.Destroy;
begin
  SortCriteria.Free;
  inherited;
end;



    
function TIDComparer.Compare(const Left, Right: TRecordObject): Integer;
begin
  if Left.ID > Right.ID then
    Result := 1
  else if Left.ID < Right.ID then
    result := -1
  else
    result := 0;
end;

constructor TRecordObject.Create(aSort: Integer; aPrice, aSize: Currency; aID: string;
  aNewParam: Integer; aSecondPrice, aSecondSize: currency; aMatched: boolean);
begin
  ID := aSort;
  Price := aPrice;
  Matched := aMatched;
end;

var
  MyComparer: TSortCriteriaComparer<TRecordObject>;
  Criterion: TSortCriterion<TRecordObject>;
  MyList: TObjectList<TRecordObject>;
  MyObject: TRecordObject;
  ReturnValue: Integer;
  Result: Boolean;

function TMatchedComparer.Compare(const Left, Right: TRecordObject): Integer;
begin
  if Left.Matched > Right.Matched then
    Result := 1
  else if Left.Matched < Right.Matched then
    result := -1
  else
    result := 0;
end;

var
  SearchObject: TRecordObject;

begin
  MyComparer := TSortCriteriaComparer<TRecordObject>.Create;
  try
    Criterion := TSortCriterion<TRecordObject>.Create;
    Criterion.Ascending := True;
    Criterion.Comparer := TIDComparer.Create;
    MyComparer.AddCriterion(Criterion);

    Criterion := TSortCriterion<TRecordObject>.Create;
    Criterion.Ascending := True;
    Criterion.Comparer := TMatchedComparer.Create;
    MyComparer.AddCriterion(Criterion);

    MyList := TObjectList<TRecordObject>.Create;

    MyObject := TRecordObject.Create(26, 1, 1, '', 1, 1, 1, False);
    MyList.Add(MyObject);

    MyObject := TRecordObject.Create(26, 1, 1, '', 1, 1, 1, True);
    MyList.Add(MyObject);

    MyObject := TRecordObject.Create(24, 1, 1, '', 1, 1, 1, True);
    MyList.Add(MyObject);

    MyObject := TRecordObject.Create(24, 1, 1, '', 1, 1, 1, True);
    MyList.Add(MyObject);

    MyObject := TRecordObject.Create(34, 1, 1, '', 1, 1, 1, False);
    MyList.Add(MyObject);

    MyList.Sort(MyComparer);

    SearchObject := TRecordObject.Create(26, 1, 1, '', 1, 1, 1, True);

    // Result=3 (correct)
    Result := MyList.BinarySearch(SearchObject, ReturnValue, MyComparer);

    Writeln(Result);
    Writeln('ReturnValue with BinarySearch=' + IntToStr(ReturnValue));

    //Result=-1=not found (incorrect)
    ReturnValue := MyList.IndexOf(SearchObject);
    Writeln('ReturnValue with IndexOf=' + IntToStr(ReturnValue));
    Readln;

  finally
    Criterion.Free;
    MyComparer.Free;
    MyList.Free;
  end;
end.
```

If I use `TObjectList<T>.BinarySearch` I have the correct result of '3' but if I use `TObjectList<T>.IndexOf` then I have -1 (not found).

SearchObject is used here only to make sure the two objects passed to .BinarySearch and IndexOf are the same.

I tried to execute .IndexOf before .BinarySearch because I thought that after a search something had to be resetted but that did not work either.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I have also replaced `TObjectList<T>` with `TList<T>` but the same error is still there.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - It does not but I thought it would not matter in this case. My understanding is IndexOf does sequential researches from the first element to the last. Therefore, MyList.Index would go through every single item of MyList starting from the first and as soon as an item matches the parameter I have passed - TRecordObject.Create(26, 1, 1, '', 1, 1, 1, True) - then it would return the position as result. Isn't this what .IndexOf does ?

Comment: It does, but it uses the comparer you provide to do that, or the default comparer otherwise. Do you know what the default comparer does?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I think I know what you mean now. TObjectList (and TList<T>) knows if an object in its list matches the one I pass to .IndexOf based on the rules in the comparer and NOT if the object I pass has the same data of one item in the list. This makes sense because the rules I set in the comparer are there for broader purposes,, to sort the list is one purpose but also for the comparison equal or different.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I suppose the Object Identity is the reference (pointer) to the object. If two variables refer to the same object then the identity is verified. In my case one variable is MyObject := TRecordObject.Create(26.... and refer to one object and the other variable is SearchObject := TRecordObject.Create(26.... and refer to another one. As the two variables are instantiated they cannot refer to the same object hence IndexOf cannot find anything.

Comment: That is correct....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The binary search call is passed your custom comparer, and so knows how to identify the objects according to the rule that you codify there. But your call to `IndexOf` is not passed your comparer, and since you didn't provide one when you created the collection, the default comparer is used.

The default comparer uses object identity, and since your search object is not in the collection, -1 is returned, which is the correct answer to the question you asked.

Solution: pass the comparer to the collection constructor.

```
MyList := TObjectList<TRecordObject>.Create(MyComparer);
```